Memory Leaks in C, realloc
I am doing a project in C about reading spells from a file and in the code report it says I am not freeing all the memory used.  I used leaks (a terminal command) to help me find the leak and this was the response:
Leak: 0x152008200  size=3584  zone: MallocStackLoggingLiteZone_0x104e10000   realloc in read_feiticos_from  C  memoryleak
    Call stack: 0x184da90e0 (dyld) start | 0x1048178d4 (memoryleak) main  F_MOOSHAK.c:389 | 0x104817680 (memoryleak) test_F  F_MOOSHAK.c:346 | 0x10481700c (memoryleak) read_feiticos_from  F_MOOSHAK.c:221 | 0x184f651e4 (libsystem_malloc.dylib) _realloc | 0x184f64ae0 (libsystem_malloc.dylib) _malloc_zone_realloc 

And this is the code in question:
Feitico* read_feitico_from(FILE *stream) {
    if (stream == NULL) return NULL;

    char nome[100], castTime[100], escola[100];
    int nivel, alcance, duracao, concentracao;
    char *description = malloc(1000 * sizeof(char)); // Dynamically allocate memory for description
    if (description == NULL) {
        printf("Failed to allocate memory for description.\n");
        return NULL;
    }
    description[0] = '\0';

    if (fscanf(stream, "%99[^\n] %d %99s %99[^\n] %d %d %d ", nome, &nivel, escola, castTime, &alcance, &duracao, &concentracao) == 7) {
        char buffer[1000];
        while (fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), stream) != NULL) {
            if (strcmp(buffer, "\\EOD\n") == 0 || strcmp(buffer, "\\EOD") == 0) break; // Correctly identifying end of description
            size_t neededSize = strlen(description) + strlen(buffer) + 1;
            if (neededSize > 1000) {
                description = realloc(description, neededSize * 2); // Adjusting size as needed
                if (!description) {
                    printf("Failed to reallocate memory for description.\n");
                    return NULL;
                }
            }
            strcat(description, buffer);
        }
        Feitico *novoFeitico = create_feitico(nome, castTime, escola, nivel, alcance, duracao, concentracao, description);
        if (novoFeitico == NULL) {
            printf("Invalid Spell: %s\n", nome);
            free(description); // Free description only if create_feitico fails
            return NULL;
        }
        // Do not free description here as it's used within novoFeitico
        return novoFeitico;
    } 
    else {
        free(description); // Free description if the initial read fails
        return NULL;
    }
}



Feitico** read_feiticos_from(FILE *stream, int* out_size) {
    if (stream == NULL || out_size == NULL) return NULL;

    *out_size = 0;
    Feitico* feitico;
    int capacity = 100;
    Feitico** feiticos = malloc(capacity * sizeof(Feitico*));
    if (!feiticos) {
        printf("Erro de alocação de memória\n");
        return NULL;
    }
    while (!feof(stream)) {
        feitico = read_feitico_from(stream);
        if (feitico != NULL) {
            if (*out_size == capacity) {
                capacity *= 2;
                Feitico** temp = realloc(feiticos, capacity * sizeof(Feitico*));
                if (!temp) {
                    printf("Erro de realocação de memória\n");
                    for (int i = 0; i < *out_size; ++i) {
                        free_feitico(feiticos[i]);
                    }
                    free(feiticos); 
                    return NULL;
                }
                feiticos = temp;
            }
            feiticos[*out_size] = feitico;
            (*out_size)++;
        }
    }
    return feiticos;
}

It's later used in main like this:
else if (strcmp("LOAD", comando) == 0) {
            char ficheiroParaLoad[40];
            if (fgets(ficheiroParaLoad, 40, stdin) != NULL) {
                sscanf(ficheiroParaLoad," %s",ficheiroParaLoad);
                if (ficheiroParaLoad[0] == '\n') { 
                    printf("Invalid command arguments!\n");
                }
                else {
                    FILE *file = fopen(ficheiroParaLoad, "r");
                    if (file == NULL) {
                        printf("Invalid file or error opening file!\n");
                    } 
                    else {
                        for (int i = 0; i < numeroFeiticos; i++) {
                            free_feitico(feiticosLidos[i]);
                        }
                        feiticosLidos = NULL;
                        numeroFeiticos=0;
    
                        feiticosLidos = read_feiticos_from(file, &numeroFeiticos);
                        if (feiticosLidos == NULL) {
                            printf("Error loading spells from file!\n");
                
                        }
                        printf("%d spells successfully loaded.\n", numeroFeiticos);
                        fclose(file);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

And at the end of the iteration, I think I am freeing the memory correctly like this:
 for(int i = 0; i < numeroFeiticos; i++){
        free_feitico(feiticosLidos[i]);
    }

For reference, free_feitico frees the memory of each spell because in the constructor I use strdup in some of the spell's arguments.
I tried to look for all the mallocs in the code, but when using the leaks tool, it told me the leak was there, but I don't understand how it leaks; doesn't malloc transfer the memory allocated to the new address?

Did you free the feiticosLidos memory anywhere? You are only showing freeing the individual contents of the array.

Yes i do, im sorry for not showing but after the iteration and after freeing every indiviudal spell i free the array it self

So in your main code that you have shown, you free feiticosLidos after the for loop and before the feiticosLidos = NULL; line, but you removed that line of code before pasting it here?

OT: sscanf(ficheiroParaLoad," %s",ficheiroParaLoad); Oooo... Same buffer for source and destination is likely to be very bad news... One cannot presume copying bytes will proceed from left-to-right...

This requires a [mcve]. Clone your code. Remove everything related to what you do with the data, then leave only loading and freeing. See if you still have the memory leak. Then edit your question with something we can really debug.

But i am only posting the 2 functions that read from the file and then the code in the test that calls them, i was trying to check if i need to free some memmory after i left the functions...

This is exactly why we cannot reproduce your problem. If you care about your question, follow the [ask] and post a [mcve]. People here will help you out. If you don't want to put effort in your question, why should anyone else do it?

Try compiling with -fsanitize=address -O0 -g (instead of using leaks, which, IIRC is Mac's answer to valgrind). This will add extra code that will [likely] stop at the exact line that caused the error.
